# How to add dynamic choices to SPFx 1.13.1 ACE QuickView

Tags: spfx, spfx-aces

So I have the Adaptive card working in the adaptive card [desiner](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/).

The QuickView JSON is this:

```json
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
      {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "${strVacationType}",
          "wrap": true
      },
      {
          "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
          "value": "${defaultTypeId}",
          "choices": [
              {
                  "$data": "${types}",
                  "title": "${Title}",
                  "value": "${Id}"
              }
          ],
          "placeholder": "Select Vacation Type",
          "id": "vacType"
      },
      {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "${strVacationStartDate}",
          "wrap": true
      },
      {
          "type": "Input.Date",
          "id": "vacStartDate"
      },
      {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "${strVacationEndDate}",
          "wrap": true
      },
      {
          "type": "Input.Date",
          "id": "vacEndDate"
      },
      {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "${strVacationFeeOptions}",
          "wrap": true
      },
      {
          "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
          "value": "${feeOptions[0].key}",
          "choices": [
              {
                  "$data": "${feeOptions}",
                  "title": "${text}",
                  "value": "${key}"
              }
          ],
          "placeholder": "Placeholder text",
          "id": "vacFee"
      },
      {
          "type": "ActionSet",
          "actions": [
              {
                  "type": "Action.Submit",
                  "style": "positive",
                  "id": "vacAddSubmit",
                  "title": "${strAddVacation}"
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
}
```

and the data JSON is this:

```json
{
    "strVacationType": "Type",
    "strVacationStartDate": "Start Date",
    "strVacationEndDate": "End Date",
    "strVacationFeeOptions": "Fee",
    "defaultTypeId": 1,
    "strAddVacation": "Add",
    "types": [
        {
            "Title": "Põhipuhkus",
            "vacTypeMapping": "vacType1",
            "vacTypeDefaultVal": 28,
            "Id": 1,
            "vacTypeExcludeHolidays": true,
            "vacTypeRequiredChildInfo": false
        },
        {
            "Title": "Lisapuhkus",
            "vacTypeMapping": "vacType2",
            "vacTypeDefaultVal": 0,
            "Id": 2,
            "vacTypeExcludeHolidays": true,
            "vacTypeRequiredChildInfo": false
        },
        {
            "Title": "Lapsepuhkus",
            "vacTypeMapping": "vacType3",
            "vacTypeDefaultVal": null,
            "Id": 3,
            "vacTypeExcludeHolidays": false,
            "vacTypeRequiredChildInfo": false
        },
        {
            "Title": "Lapsepuhkus tasustamata",
            "vacTypeMapping": "vacType4",
            "vacTypeDefaultVal": 0,
            "Id": 4,
            "vacTypeExcludeHolidays": false,
            "vacTypeRequiredChildInfo": false
        },
        {
            "Title": "Puudega lapse puhkus",
            "vacTypeMapping": "vacType5",
            "vacTypeDefaultVal": 0,
            "Id": 5,
            "vacTypeExcludeHolidays": false,
            "vacTypeRequiredChildInfo": false
        },
        {
            "Title": "Lapsehoolduspuhkus",
            "vacTypeMapping": "vacType6",
            "vacTypeDefaultVal": null,
            "Id": 6,
            "vacTypeExcludeHolidays": false,
            "vacTypeRequiredChildInfo": false
        },
        {
            "Title": "Isapuhkus",
            "vacTypeMapping": "vacType7",
            "vacTypeDefaultVal": 0,
            "Id": 7,
            "vacTypeExcludeHolidays": false,
            "vacTypeRequiredChildInfo": false
        },
        {
            "Title": "Töövõimetuspensionäri lisapuhkus",
            "vacTypeMapping": "vacType8",
            "vacTypeDefaultVal": 0,
            "Id": 8,
            "vacTypeExcludeHolidays": true,
            "vacTypeRequiredChildInfo": false
        },
        {
            "Title": "Õppepuhkus",
            "vacTypeMapping": "vacType9",
            "vacTypeDefaultVal": 20,
            "Id": 9,
            "vacTypeExcludeHolidays": false,
            "vacTypeRequiredChildInfo": false
        },
        {
            "Title": "Õppepuhkus tasustamata",
            "vacTypeMapping": "vacType10",
            "vacTypeDefaultVal": 10,
            "Id": 10,
            "vacTypeExcludeHolidays": false,
            "vacTypeRequiredChildInfo": false
        },
        {
            "Title": "Õppepuhkus miinimumpalgaga",
            "vacTypeMapping": "vacType11",
            "vacTypeDefaultVal": 0,
            "Id": 11,
            "vacTypeExcludeHolidays": false,
            "vacTypeRequiredChildInfo": false
        },
        {
            "Title": "Palgata puhkus",
            "vacTypeMapping": null,
            "vacTypeDefaultVal": 0,
            "Id": 12,
            "vacTypeExcludeHolidays": false,
            "vacTypeRequiredChildInfo": false
        }
    ],
    "feeOptions": [
        {
            "key": 2,
            "text": "Koos palgaga"
        },
        {
            "key": 1,
            "text": "Enne puhkust"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I test out the ACE I get the following error (multiple times):

> "All choices in an Input.ChoiceSet must have their title and value properties set."

As far as I can tell the ACE is set up correctly, but it does not render for me. The funny part is that when I use the sample from Microsoft [here](https://adaptivecardsci.z5.web.core.windows.net/samples/CalendarReminderWithLabels.html) then that works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

So after some trial and error I found the issue. The `Choice` takes only a `string` value as documented here:
https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Input.Choice.html